# Ubuntu 12.04.3 - Graphics Driver: Default vs Nvidia 319-recommended vs Nvidia 319-updated

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend

Background: 
I switched from default driver to Nvidia-319-recommended. I am guessing that this update has caused issues with Keyboard shortcuts, battery status icon disappearing as well as power management issues as speculated by others. Closing laptop lid no longer suspends laptop - It has to be manually done by licking 'suspend' before closing lid.

Question: How do you restore the original/default graphics driver?

Thanks for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be solved with "restarting the Lightdm display manager".
So first of all try :

```
 restart lightdm
```

And if the problem is still present, you can try this:

```
 sudo apt-get purge nvidia
```

But, unrelated to your question, I suggest you try to update your driver to version 325 and then install Bumblebee on it (before deciding to downgrade to nvidia-current) :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia

sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then adding Nvidia and Bumblebee PPAs:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-325 nvidia-settings-325
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

P.S : Bumblebee is a utility to manually switch between integrated VGA card (Intel) and High-End VGA card (Nvidia). see [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) for more information.